# Puppet: variables inside variables

Tags: puppet

Hopefully a simple question, is there a way I can put variables inside other variables? In my particular use case, I am trying to get tricky to have puppet install a whole bunch of binaries (ant, maven, jdk's etc)

Let's say I have the following manifest:

```
$package_name = [ 'ant', 'maven' ]
$package_ant_versions = [ '1.7.1', '1.8.4', '1.9.4' ]
$package_ant_prefix = 'apache-ant-'
$package_ant_suffix = '-src.tar.gz'
$package_maven_versions = [ '3.0.4' ]
$package_maven_prefix = 'apache-maven-'
$package_maven_suffix = '.tgz'
$path = 'repo.domain.com/software'
```

So there are my variables. Now I am trying to write an exec statement that will iterate through all packages and variables and download them locally, so I may install them.

Here is my attempt at the command:

```
exec { 'download-packages': 
    command => "/usr/bin/aws s3 cp ${path}/${package_name}/${package_${package_name}_prefix}/{package_${package_name}_versions}/${package_${package_name}_suffix} /tmp"
}
```

The way I had hoped it would work was that it would iterate through all variables. For example, with the defined variables the commands that would be run are:

```
/usr/bin/aws s3 cp repo.domain.com/software/ant/apache-ant-1.7.1-src.tar.gz /tmp
/usr/bin/aws s3 cp repo.domain.com/software/ant/apache-ant-1.8.4-src.tar.gz /tmp
/usr/bin/aws s3 cp repo.domain.com/software/ant/apache-ant-1.9.4-src.tar.gz /tmp
/usr/bin/aws s3 cp repo.domain.com/software/maven/apache-maven-3.0.4.tgz /tmp
```

The end result is that I simply want to add/change versions in the manifest (e.g. I could go in and add ant version 1.9.3 simply by changing:

```
$package_ant_versions = [ '1.7.1', '1.8.4', '1.9.4' ]
```

to

```
$package_ant_versions = [ '1.7.1', '1.8.4', '1.9.3', '1.9.4' ]
```

And have puppet do the rest (assuming the file is available in the location it is trying to download from).

I am sure I am doing this all wrong, but I hope the end result I am trying to get to is clear. It seems to break when I try and put variables inside variables:

```
${package_${package_name}_prefix}
${package_${package_name}_versions}
${package_${package_name}_suffix}
```

Any help to get this working or achieve something similar would be really helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Someone has built [something similar](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/puppet-users/AcB06pxHrAw/pzE4gVE92S0J) a while back. - Is there a reason you don't have variables like `$packages = { 'ant' => { 'versions' => [ ... ], prefix => 'apache-ant-', ... }, 'maven => { ... } }`, i.e. a sane hash structure?

Comment: Hi Felix and thanks. I am learning Puppet and going on training soon, so the only reason I don't have variables defined in a 'sane hash structure' is because I haven't come across it. I will try this (and Raul's suggestion) and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Felix. So I have created a more sane hash structure:

`$packages = {
        'ant' => {
            'versions' => [
                '1.7.1',
                '1.8.4',
                '1.9.4',
            ],
            'prefix' => 'apache-ant-',
            'suffix' => '-src.tar.gz',
        },
        'maven' => {
            'versions' => [
                '3.0.4',
            ],
            'prefix' => 'apache-maven-',
            'suffix' => '-bin.tar.gz',
        }
    }`

Any way you could help me put that into a one liner exec statement? Not sure how to do that using that structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, as was noted, use a structure like the following.

```
$packages = { 
    'ant' => { 
        'versions' => [ '1.7.1', '1.8.4', '1.9.4', ], 
        'prefix' => 'apache-ant-', 
        'suffix' => '-src.tar.gz',
    },
    'maven' => { 
        'versions' => [ '3.0.4', ],
        'prefix' => 'apache-maven-', 
        'suffix' => '-bin.tar.gz',
    }
}
```

Note that the array of versions cannot be sensibly used in a single exec resource. I think you want this:

```
define software_download($versions, $prefix, $suffix) {
    software_version_download { $versions:
        software => $name,
        prefix => $prefix,
        suffix => $suffix,
    }
}

define software_version_download($software, $prefix, $suffix) {
    $version = $name
    exec { "download-$software-$version": 
        command => "/usr/bin/aws s3 cp ${path}/${software}/${prefix}${version}${suffix} /tmp",
    }
}
```

The `define software_download` accepts your data and multiplexes it to the `software_version_download` define, passing each distinct version as the resource `$name`. From that, the final command is constructed.

If your data is in the hash, you can `create_resources('software_download', $packages)`, or less magically via manifest code:

```
software_download { 
    'ant': 
        'versions' => [ '1.7.1', '1.8.4', '1.9.4', ], 
        'prefix' => 'apache-ant-', 
        'suffix' => '-src.tar.gz';
    'maven':
        'versions' => [ '3.0.4', ],
        'prefix' => 'apache-maven-', 
        'suffix' => '-bin.tar.gz';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Felix, that's perfect and now I've managed to get my installers downloading to the correct location. I also added a `creates => "/tmp/${prefix}${version}${suffix}"` to ensure that the files aren't downloaded every puppet run.

I did notice that I need to put other variables (for example `${path}`) inside `define software_version_download` as having it at the top of the file doesn't work. Any idea why that is?

Comment: Global variables are a fickle mistress. Getting stuff in scope is a safe design. - That being said, it *should* have worked, but it's hard to tell without expecting larger parts of your code base.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using [inline_template](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/function.html#inlinetemplate):

```
exec { 'download-packages': 
    command => inline_template("/usr/bin/aws s3 cp ${path}/${package_name}/<%=package_${package_name}_prefix%>/<%=package_${package_name}_versions%>/<%=package_${package_name}_suffix%> /tmp")
}
```

But, as @FelixFrank says, maybe is preferrible a structured way.

That solves the problem of variables inside variables. For the array problem, you could [emulate](http://backdrift.org/puppet-foreach-for-loop-workaround) a foreach statement:

```
$package_name= [ "ant", "maven" ]

define download-packages() {
  exec { 'download-packages-$name': 
      command => "/usr/bin/aws s3 cp ${path}/${name}/${package_${name}_prefix}/{package_${name}_versions}/${package_${name}_suffix} /tmp"
  }
}
download-packages{ $package_name:}
```

Comment: Hi Raul, thanks for your reply. I am trying your answer and it certainly gets me around my original error, but now I have this problem. I have the following array variable:

    `$package_name = [
        'ant',
        'maven',
    ]`

And then your command as you said:

`command => inline_template("/usr/bin/aws s3 cp ${path}/${package_name}/<%=package_${package_name}_prefix%>/<%=package_${package_name}_versions%>/<%=package_${package_name}_suffix%> /tmp")`

However when I do a puppet run I get the following error:
`Could not find value for 'package_antmaven_prefix`

Any suggestions?